# How to know the active presentation's size?

Tags: excel, office-interop, powerpoint-2013, vba

Is it possible to know the active presentation's size on the fly? I mean, we don't have to save as, and check on the file's size.

I tried to search for a similar property of the PowerPoint._Application.ActivePresentation, but cannot find out.

Any recommendation?

Thanks

Note: I am using PowerPoint 2013, C#, VS Ultimate 2013

Comment: File size in bytes or slides?

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to save the presentation first.

Answer (score 1):

No. Because the format for storing the presentation in memory is different from the XML format used to export it to a file system object.